# The system requirements are not satisfied HAMX. Проблема с android stydio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intel, device

Начал загрузку HAXM, так как проблемы в android studio и пишет ошибку

> The system requirements are not satisfied

и такой лог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: первая строка в поиске EPT supported - no 
https://github.com/paolo-projects/auto-unlocker/issues/31

Comment: Я смотрел там, но что то не то. Не получается а если делать виртуальную машины я думаю это не то что мне нужно

Comment: что именно не получается?

Comment: Найди включение EPT. Это 5 пункт в ответе на гитхабе( где огромный ответ с картинками ), я не нашёл как зайти в конфигурацию процессора чтобы выставить  EPT. Подозреваю что надо создать виртуальную машину, но немного боюсь, так как вдруг не удалится или комп сгорит всё в таком духе. Всё остальные пункты сделаны.

Answer (score 0):

У моего процессора не поддерживается SLAT. Вот так я это понял:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А раз не поддерживается значит создание виртуальной машины невозможно(